# asyncIO - for loop to search in a file

Tags: python, json, python-asyncio

I have a CSV file where there are 15000 mac adresses and I would like to find the vendor mapping for each of these mac addresses.

I have a json file where I can find all the vendor mapping by mac prefix like this:
`oui.json`

```
 {
   "VendorMapping": [
      {
         "_mac_prefix": "00:00:00",
         "_vendor_name": "XEROX CORPORATION"
      },
      {
         "_mac_prefix": "00:00:01",
         "_vendor_name": "XEROX CORPORATION"
      },
      {
         "_mac_prefix": "00:00:02",
         "_vendor_name": "XEROX CORPORATION"
      },
      {
         "_mac_prefix": "00:00:03",
         "_vendor_name": "XEROX CORPORATION"
      },
      {
         "_mac_prefix": "00:00:04",
         "_vendor_name": "XEROX CORPORATION"
      },
....
```

I started my script by making a foor loop in my CSV and a foor loop in the json to find the matching vendor mapping for each mac address of my CSV:

```
import json
import os
from time import time

start = time()
f = open("oui.json")
data = json.load(f)
file = open("data.csv")
content = file.readlines()[1:]

for line in content:
    mac = line.split(',')[1]
    print(mac)
    for oui in data["VendorMapping"]:
        if mac.upper().startswith(oui["_mac_prefix"]):
            print(oui["_vendor_name"])
            break
print(f'Total time: {time() - start}')
```

It took me 49 seconds to get all the vendor mapping for all the mac adresses. But I want to make it much faster.

For that, I decided to use asyncIO like that:

```
import json
import asyncio
import os
from time import time

start = time()
f = open('oui.json')
data = json.load(f)
file = open("api/data.csv")
content = file.readlines()[1:]

tasks = []

async def vendormapping(line):
    mac = line.split(',')[1]
    print(mac)
    for oui in data["VendorMapping"]:
        if mac.upper().startswith(oui["_mac_prefix"]):
            print(oui["_vendor_name"])
            break

async def main():
    for line in content:
        tasks.append(vendormapping(line))
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    
asyncio.run(main())
print(f"All took {time() - start}")
```

I think I'm doing something wrong because it's taking 39 seconds to proceed. I was expecting something faster.
Can someone please help me?

Thank you,

Comment: There's nothing asynchronous in function `async def vendormapping()` (you're not using `await`). Looking at the structure of `oui.json` - is `"_mac_prefix"` always in the format `XX:XX:XX` - 6 digits?

Comment: I thought the await was only for the main function. How should I put it also in the vendormapping function? No, sometimes there are 8 or 10 digits. Thanks for your help

Comment: `await` is generally only used when awaiting a courotine (for example `asyncio.sleep` or sending/receiving data over network). In your `vendormapping()` I don't see any place for awaiting.

Comment: I recommend restructuring the structure of `oui.json`. For example change it to simple mapping `{'XX:XX:XX': 'Xerox corp.', 'XX:YY:ZZ': 'Xerox corp.', ... }`

Comment: Ok if I restructure the json like that, I don't know how to find the key which is matching with my MAC address. So will I need to make a for loop in the new json also in this case?

Comment: Please edit your question with some sample data of `data.csv` and I might come up with a solution.

Comment: My data.csv file is a simple csv with 5 columns, one of these is "MAC" column and there are 15000 rows. I'm sorry I can't show the data in it, as it is from my company.
The restructuration of the json is good, I just don't know how to find directly the matching key knowing that the key is just a part of my Mac address from the CSV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

asyncio is a single threaded IO. As in even though you're async you're not actually processing anything in parallel. AsyncIO is more used when there is a lot of waiting involved in your workloads. In this scenario there is no waiting. its just pure throughput.

Ive refactored your code to use multiprocessing instead. Which is more suited to raw throughput than AsyncIO. In my testing i cut the time down from 15 seconds to 4. (using spoofed data i guessed)

```
def vendormapping(line):
    mac = line.split(',')[1]
    print(mac)
    for oui in data["VendorMapping"]:
        if mac.upper().startswith(oui["_mac_prefix"]):
            print(oui["_vendor_name"])
            break


def main():
    with Pool() as p:
        p.map(vendormapping, content)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    print(f"All took {time() - start}")
```

Comment: Nice, thank you very much. It tooks me 14 seconds to proceed. Thanks a lot

Comment: As a side note you can move the `mac.upper()` out of the for loop. So that you only call it once per mac address instead of every time you want to compare.